# "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h file not found" error after changing project name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I had a Xcode project working fine. I changed the name of the project, closed Xcode and reopened the project.

Now everything is cool except for a line in **Bridging-Header.h**

There is a line which includes `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` in my **Bridging-Header.h**

Error message is `'SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h' file not found`

I changed the name to the old one but still same issue. What can I do for that ?